# Firebase Push Notification Android when application is closed

Tags: android

I'm developing an application dealing with push notifications. I have used firebase for this purpose. The requirement is as such on clicking notification , the 3rd activity of the application must open up . I was successful in achieving the same when application is in background and foreground . But when application is killed and on tap of the received notification , it takes me to launcher screen . what should i do to redirect a notification click to the activity i want when the application is killed ?

Comment: is there any condition in your app that some data pass from launcher activity?

Comment: and inside your manifest launcher activity has intent-filter so opens first

Comment: yes the launcher activity has a bundle to the next screen . but i have the values of the bundle in my notification payload . So i retrieve the data using intent. but the problem is redirection . how to redirect to 3rd screen on tap of the notification?